Зависание sql запросов
Есть следующая проблема: когда лазаю в phpmyadmin и кликаю там что-то, например, переключаюсь между таблицами, или редактирую вручную несколько значений подряд, то замечаю, что раз в несколько действий одно из этих действий тормозится на секунд 5-6, потом отвисает и выполняется. Это не только в phpmyadmin, т.к. в телеграмм боте, где у меня стоит на кнопке вызов запроса в БД тоже это наблюдается: обычно все быстро, но одно из нескольких нажатий подвисает так же на секунд 5-6. нагрузки никакой на сервер нет, запросы простые, параллельно никаких запросов не летит, поэтому не понимаю, с чем это связано, может какие-то настройки базы? Если что, у меня стоит hestia (от неё сразу и php, и mysql, и phpmyadmin)

Недостаток памяти (RAM) может вызывать задержки. У меня так было – увеличили память, и теперь работает без задержек. Проверьте настройки MySQL и используемую память на сервере
